# To put a link over selected text - Wrap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have someone plugin, which can upload the file and put the link for this file, but he insert file name into link..

```
this.insertHTML('<a href="'+this.sanitizeURL(a)+'">'+b+"</a>")
```

`b` is the upload file name. I wanna change `b` to selected text into editor...

How to do it?

Comment: which editor? OS editor?

Comment: @Shubhranshu No, it's Joomla editor Froala Editor... I just want edit this plugin a little bit